# PySimpleGUI doesn't reroute cprint of mulitprocessing to its Multiline element

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, pysimplegui

I am using `multiprocessing` module along with `PySimpleGUI`.

Instead of `Multiline` everything gets printed in my IDE console. This problem only happens when I use `multiprocessing`. Other function with `sg.cprint` statement and even with simple `print` statement would print the result in `Multiline`, as it should.

Here's my code, that shows the problem

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import multiprocessing


def func(link: str):
    sg.cprint(link)
    sg.cprint('string')
    print(link)
    print('string')


def make_window():
    layout = [[sg.Multiline(key='-Multiline-', reroute_stdout=True)],
              [[sg.Button('Start', key='-Start-')]]]

    window = sg.Window('Forum', layout, finalize=True)

    sg.cprint_set_output_destination(window, '-Multiline-')

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        elif event == '-Start-':
            sg.cprint('Process has started')
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func,
                                              args=('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask',),
                                              daemon=True)
            process.start()

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_window()
```

I have tried to reroute everything to `Multiline` with `reroute_stdout=True` — doesn't work.
According to so called "Cookbook" of `PySimpleGUI`, it's possible to reroute print like this:

```
window['-Multiline-'].print('Testing 1 2 3')
```

It doesn't work if I put something like that in my function (I assume that is because my function is above the GUI code)

In conclusion - the issue doesn't appear when I use `threading` module. But `multiprocessing` solves other problem - it allows me to terminate a process with `.terminate()`. Couldn't do that with `threading`as easily.

My application uses OOP and a bit more complicated than the code I provided.

Comment: With `multiprocessing` each process runs in its own separate memoryspace, so globals in one cannot be accessed by code running in another. The output of the `cprint()`calls in the second process can't be seen by the `PySimpleGUI` running in the main process. You don't see these problem with `threading` because everything is running in the same memoryspace.

Answer (score 0):

> When running a subprocess, you get an entirely new environment. You can't share global variables for example.

> Python essentially runs a completely new Python interpreter instance whenever you start() a multiprocess.Process instance and since different processes get different stacks they don't get to share the internal memory so Python actually pickles the passed arguments, sends them to the Process and then unpickles them there creating an illusion that both processes (the parent and the child) have the same data.

I know nothing about library `multiprocessing`, following code work, but maybe not perfect.

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import multiprocessing

import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(queue:multiprocessing.Queue, link: str):
    for i in range(10):
        queue.put(f'Message #{i}')
        sleep(1)

def thread(window, url):
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=(queue, url), daemon=True)
    process.start()
    while process.is_alive():
        if not queue.empty():
            line = queue.get()
            window.write_event_value("Message", line)
    while not queue.empty():
        line = queue.get()
        window.write_event_value("Message", line)
    window.write_event_value("Message", 'Process has stopped')

def make_window():
    layout = [[sg.Multiline(key='-Multiline-', size=(40, 10), reroute_stdout=True)],
              [[sg.Button('Start', key='-Start-')]]]

    window = sg.Window('Forum', layout, finalize=True)

    sg.cprint_set_output_destination(window, '-Multiline-')

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break

        elif event == '-Start-':
            sg.cprint('Process has started')
            url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
            threading.Thread(target=thread, args=(window, url), daemon=True).start()
        elif event == 'Message':
            message = values[event]
            print(message)

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make_window()
```